Good Replacement of 'ResizeObserver' while detecting the size of a div and calling a function post that
I'm encountering an issue with the use of "ResizeObserver."
I have a setup where a parent div (class="parent") contains a child div (class="child"). This child div displays content retrieved from a database, which is determined by the height of the parent div. Specifically, the content consists of rows, each with a height of x pixels, so the total rows displayed are calculated as floor(heightOfParentDiv/x).
My goal is to dynamically update the viewport of the child div based on changes in the height of the parent div, achievable by invoking a function (func). I've considered using ResizeObserver on the parent div to trigger func whenever the parent's size changes.
However, I'm concerned that "ResizeObserver" might be resource-intensive and potentially affect performance.
I've also experimented with 'requestAnimationFrame()' but am uncertain about which option offers better performance.
Could anyone provide insights into analyzing these two functionalities in terms of performance? Additionally, is there another method to monitor height changes and apply those updates through the func API?
I am expecting some other way (may be better) to deal with dynamic update of content based on change in height.
